# Xml serializing dynamic string to boolean

Tags: c#, json, xml

Below is an instance of a simple job scheduler which parses xml dynamic strings to json:

**XML**

```
<Navigations>
      <Navigation Name="facebook" Active ="0" ></Navigation>
</Navigations>
```

**c#**

```
List<NavigationData> nds = new List<NavigationData>();
foreach (object cnav in (IEnumerable)c.Navigations)
{
    NavigationData nd = new NavigationData();
    nd.Name = (string)((dynamic)cnav).Name;
    nd.Active = XmlConvert.ToBoolean((string)((dynamic)cnav).Active); // 3 
    nds.Add(nd);
}
transitContent.NavigationData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nds);
```

The above program throws an exception at line 3 as:

1. failed to convert string to boolean with `XMLConvert.ToBoolean`
2. not able to recognize string with `Convert.ToBoolean`

An other type conversions possibele in this scenario? The expected result should be:

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "facebook",
        "Active": false
    }
]
```

Comment: What's parsing the XML? Fundamentally you should convert the value to an `int` and then check whether it's non-zero, but it's possible there are much better approaches than the ones you're using...

Comment: To check for null, i have this:  `Active = (n.Attribute("Active") != null) ? n.Attribute("Active").Value : string.Empty`

Comment: So do you want to treat a missing attribute as active or inactive? You might want to change the check in my answer to "cnav.Active == "1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, "0" isn't a valid value for a Boolean. It sounds like you possibly want something like:

```
List<NavigationData> nds = new List<NavigationData>();
foreach (dynamic cnav in (IEnumerable)c.Navigations)
{
    NavigationData nd = new NavigationData();
    nd.Name = cnav.Name;
    nd.Active = cnav.Active != "0";
    nds.Add(nd);
}
transitContent.NavigationData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nds);
```

This is assuming that `cnav` will expose all properties as strings (as their execution-time type).

Comment: What happens when in xml:  `Active = "1"` ? Will it set it to true. I know `nd.Active` type is boolean

Comment: @Dev-One: Well what would `"1" != "0"` return?